# 2d Game Algorithm - Calculate object speed based on screen size

Tags: android, math, libgdx

I am making an android app using LibGdx where a colored tile is put in the center of the screen and you have to swipe to to the left, right, top, or bottom, based on the color. Since android has so many screen sizes, it came to my attention that it wouldn't be fair to have the same speed of movement for the tile. On bigger devices, it would take more time for the tile to reach it's destination. Basically, I want to calculate a speed that will move my tile from the center of the screen to the left, right, top, or bottom, in the same amount of time as my TIME variable. The TIME constant is set to 0.5 . Anyone have any idea on how I could calculate the speed I need at runtime for each screen size? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, speed is [LENGTH / TIME].

If you want your tile to take `x` seconds to reach the side of the screen, you could make it go `HALF_THE_SCREEN / x (in seconds)`.

You need to get the dimensions of the screen and divide those dimensions by the time you want the movement to last.

So, if the screen is 400 pixels wide, let it be 200 pixels per second to get the tile from the center to the left (200 pixels) in one second.

The same logic applies to the height of the screen.